# Can i use two actors or more in one lane in BPMN?

Tags: business-objects, bpmn, business-process-management

I am modeling some processes in a system and draw it in BPMN. But I confuse, can I use 2 actors in one lane? because they have the same task from start to end. they don't have differences in that business process. like the picture show. so can I? or how can I fix that?

This is the business process:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it shouldn't be that way.
Each actor has a specific business scope if you wanna call it.
First describe best the scope of activities involved in each actor, then look of the departments interact. Wich actor has a bigger scope than the other. Why?.

Example in your case both the first actor should take care of both 2 task, and scalate them if something happen that needs a more experienced opinion. Or just if some outcome of the first task it's outside the scope of the first actor. Let's say  :

First Actor takes care or approved checks up to $5000.
The first task involves putting all the details of the check as the amount.
When the first task end the outcome can be Greather/equals than $5000 or less than $5000.

Case 1 [amount < $5000]If the outcome it's less then a task for the first actor it's created when an action available it's to approve the check.

Case 2 [amount >= $5000] If the ourcome it's greather/equals then a new task it's made for the second actor, wich will require it's approvement.

Also to say in this scenario we will have 3 task, 2 for the first actor (input check task, approve low budget checks) and 1 for the second actor (approve of high budget checks).

Usually this over specification can be replaced by using some scalating mechanism. Usually involving timeframes required for the first task to be operated but it can't be based in other details too. Hope it helps . Best!

Answer (score 0):

This depends a good bit on some additional context.  If I were implementing this solution using a tool where the diagram is interpreted and used at runtime, my answer may be different than if I'm simply using BPMN as a good tool for capturing my Business Process.

The first question I would have if my customer modeled a process in this manner is "So, please confirm, based on this diagram, it for every instance of the process it is equally valid for either the Visitor or the Admin to execute task 1 and 2."  That seems a bit unlikely to me, since based on that, any visitor could execute these tasks, no matter what their relationship to the underlying instance of the process.

For example, lets say you were capturing something where I, as the visitor should fill out a form (task 1), but you are trying to accomidate that in some situations the Admin might fill out the form for me.  If makes sense that either I can fill out the form for myself, or the Admin can, but it doesn't make sense that you, a person totally unrelated to me and not an Admin, would be allowed to fill out the form.

If I were modeling the above scenario (who fills out the form) I would likely have a decision gateway after the start that would evaluate "Is Andrew going to do this?".  A yes would go to "Fill out form" activity for me, and a "No" would route to the "Fill out form" for the Admin.

As in many things in life, there isn't a clear answer, especially when the thing you have asked is so abstract.  I can come up with examples where either model is valid, but would need the specifics to get it right.